# Backing up dolfin browser saved passwords in bada

Tags: passwords, browser, bada, password-recovery

I'm using a Samsung Wave 2 with Bada OS on it. I'm wondering if I can see / backup my saved passwords on Dolfin Browser. I can code if required.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the l/p pairs are stored in *\User\Br\SFB\FF.dat*. I may be wrong though; it's just some hours ago that I've started examining the full file system content of Bada 1.x. Of course the file is fully encrypted.

I will quickly check out whether, after enabling TKFileExplorer on the phone itself (see the mini-tutorial at http://www.mortara.org/board/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=138#p417 for more info), you can access the full file system from inside Bada apps. To browse it from a PC, I recommend TkFileExplorer 2.4 (NOT 2.2, it didn't work with my 723) available at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=12515691&postcount=20 .

Will report back soon on the sandbox restrictions of TKFileExplorer'ed phones - hope they behave like jailbroken iOS ones (read: no sandbox any more).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Are you sure that the file is encrypted? In http://darkforestgroup.com/forum/index.php?topic=2978.0 it says file is not encrytpted but it might be an old version of Bada.

By the way, does using TKFileExplorer make my phone jailbroken and remove warranty?